# C++ process string one by line

Tags: c++, string

So I have string:

```
string message = "Hello\nHow are you?\nGood!"
```

I want to get it line by line in this format:

```
string line = "";

for (getline(message, line)) {
    // do something with the line
}
```

How can I achieve this? It doesn't matter if `getline` will be in use.

I tried to split the string by `\n` but I can't go through it with for loop

Comment: BTW:  In `string line = "";`  you don't need the `=""` part, `string line;` does the same thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getline` requires an input stream to work on.  Fortunately, we have [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) which you can probably tell from the name is a stream of a string.  Using that changes your code to

```
std::string line;
std::stringstream ss(message);
while(getline(ss, line)) {
    // do something with the line
}
```

Comment: In this case, a `std::istringstream` would suffice :)

Answer (score 2):

Using [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) ranges, you can do this with a loop over a split view:

```
for (auto line_view : std::ranges::split_view(message, "\n")) {
    std::string_view line{line_view.begin(), line_view.end()};
    // do something with the line
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03eaca2b5048dbfa)

This can avoid making multiple copies of the original string and each line, which may be worth the extra complexity depending on the size of the string.